# how to get some alphabet on string array & count some alphabet in perl

Tags: perl

> for example:
>
> Input: Testing 123 for my letter count program.
>
> Output: t = 5 e = 3 g = 2 n = 2 c = 1 i = 1 p = 1 u = 1 r = 4 o = 3 m
> = 2 a = 1 f = 1 l = 1 s = 1 y = 1

I try to code this question, but didn't worked. This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use utf8;
use warnings;

$line = <STDIN>;
$len = length($line);

$count = 0;
while($count < $len){
  print "$line[$count]\n";
  $count += 1;
}
```

So help me to code this question. Because i don't understand how to code this question

Comment: Your program doesn't even try to count individual letters. Perl strings aren't indexable like they are in other languages, but if they were then all your code would do is to print each character in a line on its own. I'm sure this isn't a professional problem and you're probably in the process of learning to program, so I don't think that just giving you a solution will help you to learn anything.

Comment: `echo 'Testing 123 for my letter count program.' | perl -E '$c{$_}++ for (map {lc} grep /\w/, split //, <>); say "$_ = $c{$_}" for keys %c'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input = 'Testing 123 for my letter count program.';
my %seen;
my @order = grep { !$seen{$_}++ } lc($input) =~ /([a-z])/ig;
print "$_ = $seen{$_}\n" for @order;
```

output

```
t = 5
e = 3
s = 1
i = 1
n = 2
g = 2
f = 1
o = 3
r = 4
m = 2
y = 1
l = 1
c = 1
u = 1
p = 1
a = 1
```

Comment: oh can you explain about "my %seen" and "my @order" in your code?

Comment: `@order` holds unique letters from the sentence and `%seen` hash holds number of occurrence for each letter. Please check https://perlmaven.com/unique-values-in-an-array-in-perl

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

my $input = 'Testing 123 for my letter count program.';
my %hash = ();
map { $hash{lc($_)}++ } grep /[a-zA-Z]/, split('', $input);
print "Output: ";
print "$_ = $hash{$_} " for(keys %hash);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Output: e = 3 y = 1 a = 1 r = 4 s = 1 g = 2 c = 1 n = 2 l = 1 t = 5 i = 1 p = 1 f = 1 m = 2 u = 1 o = 3
```